# Graph API querying Params

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to find / have better documentation than what is offered [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters)?

For example, how is it possible to:

- Filter for messages only inside 'sent folder' ?
- $filter description says  `Filters the response based on a set of criteria`. What are those criteria? Give us a simple list of what can be done. Don't expect developers to memorise all your commands or expect them do dig over 15 redirects to find query params.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to OData documentations on system query parameters for more details and sample queries. For example, this is [the link](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358) for $filter.

Regarding how to get messages for sent folder, you can use the following query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('sentItems')/messages

For other folders, it could be done in 2-steps:

1. Get folder id: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders?$filter=displayName eq 'folderName'
2. Get the messages in that folder: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('folderId from step 1')/messages

You can also try the following query (but paging does not seem to work):
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders?$filter=displayname eq 'Sent Items'&$expand=messages($skip=10)

Comment: I've found that already, which is little to no help when their api is so broken that the same query written two different ways returns different results .. when querying for emails, it will also return event messages and there is no way to filter them out